# Using only javascript, without using ajax, jquery how can we send data(sent request) to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to  JavaScript, JQuery, ajax.

I get to know using ajax and jJQuery we can sent the request to the server, but without using ajax how can we sent data.

So i want to know how we can send the request to the server using only JavaScript, without using any JQuery, ajax. to get the response(or) to post the data to the server.

Comment: What server-side technologies are you using? PHP? ASP.NET? Ruby?

Comment: @Ruskin — How would that impact how you would make a post request from the browser with JS?

Comment: Note that ajax can be both pure javascript or wrapped in a library such as jQuery. Is ajax using pure javascript acceptable or do you want to know how we used to do it before ajax or do you want to know how to do it to avoid suspicion? What's your reason for not wanting to use ajax?

Comment: @slebetman i want to know how we used to do it before ajax. no reason for not to use ajax, just i want to know is there any alternative instead of using ajax...thanks for the response

Comment: OK. But ajax also covers a wide range of techniques. So do you mean without XMLHttpRequest or without *any* form of ajax including long polling and hidden iframes?

Comment: @slebetman without any form of ajax

Comment: Submitting forms to hidden iframes isn't AJAX.

Comment: @ThiefMaster — It's a fuzzy area that depends on how, exactly, you define Ajax.

Comment: @Quentin I was trying to get a conversation going to get the asker thinking about what the server would do when it got the request ... I had forgotten about the possibility of calling static files with Ajax ... but thought either this is a homework question or the asker needed a steer to think about querystring, form posts etc.

Answer (score 3):

Call the `submit` method of a form object. (After making sure the form is set up for the post method).

```
<form method="post" action="foo">
    <input type="hidden" value="data">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    document.querySelector('form').submit();
</script>
```